# Django jquery autocomplete giving an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, autocomplete

I am developing a django application where I am using jquery autocomplete. I know that this question has been asked several times here but none of the solution is working for me. I am following this tutorial: http://flaviusim.com/blog/AJAX-Autocomplete-Search-with-Django-and-jQuery/

I have included this in my header:

```
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

in this exact same order

Then in my page, I have used:

```
{% extends "account/base.html" %}

{% load i18n %}
{% load bootstrap %}

{% block body_class %}applications{% endblock %}

{% block head_title %}{% trans "Change password" %}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}




<form action="/create_recipe_rule/{{ recipe_pk }}/" method="post">
{% csrf_token  %}





<div class="form-group ui-widget">
<label for="{{ form.content.label }}">{{ form.content.label }}:</label>
<textarea type="{{ form.content.type }}" name="{{ form.content.name }}" max_length="500" class="form-control" id="recipe_rule_content"></textarea>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
  $("#recipe_rule_content").autocomplete({
    source: "/api/get_RuleStatement/",
    minLength: 2,
  });
});
</script>


     <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Can anyone suggest where am I going wrong?

This is the error that I get in console:

> uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

Answer (score 0):

It look like Your code is executed before `jQueryUI` is loaded.

Move Your

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#recipe_rule_content").autocomplete({
    source: "/api/get_RuleStatement/",
    minLength: 2,
  });
});
</script>
```

to `<head>` after

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**

`code.jquery.com` have a problem with certificate. Try **cdnjs**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

Comment: I tried your edit, its still the same problem : (index):152 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function